# como crear signup y login en wordpress

Tags: mysql, wordpress

Mi pregunta es la siguiente como puedo crear un formulario de registro y a su vez crear el formulario de inicio de sesion en wordpress, esto yo lo eh hecho muchas veces en html php y mysql pero soy nuevo en wordpress y quisiera saber como desarrollarlo en esta plataforma

Answer (score 0):

En wordpress el formulario de registro y login es el mismo que tu usas para entrar al panel de administración /wp-login.php

Lo que debes hacer es irte a los ajustes de wordpress y permitir nuevos registros en tu web. Además deberás elegir que tipo de perfil de usuario se asignará a una persona cuando se cree una cuenta.

Después te recomiendo que instales un plugin de administración de usuarios y edites los permisos que van a tener los usuarios que se registrarán.